# check if user exists in my database

Tags: c#, database, oracle11g

I have a c# login forum that has two text-boxes

1.username

2.password

I am trying to check if the user exists in my Oracle database or not. If so, I want it to do something (like call another forum, etc...), but I'm getting an error msg that says I have a missing expression. Whats wrong with it?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isUserExist(textBox1.Text,textBox2.Text);
}

public bool isUserExist(string username,string password)
{
    try
    {
        string connstring = "data source=test_db;user id=system;password=password;";
        string statementcmd = "SELECT * FROM register_user Where UserName=@username";

        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstring);
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = statementcmd;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", username);
        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Open();
            OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (!reader.HasRows)
            { MessageBox.Show("User Name Not Found"); }

            if (!password.Equals(reader["password"].ToString()))
                 MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Password");
            reader.Close();
            }
            return true;

        }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the Read method on the DataReader before trying to access the properties.

```
if (reader.Read())
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**1.** you need to assign `parameters` before assigning commandstring to the `CommandText`.
**2.**  you need to call `Read()` `OracleDataReader` object `reader` before accessing the `records`.
**3.**   you should return true when `true` only when user is found.(in second if condition open curly braces is missing).
**4.**  you can use `using{}` block for all `IDisposable` Implemented classes in your program so that their objects `disposal` will be taken care.(so you don't need to call `Close()` on `Connection` or `Command` objects)

**Complete Solution:**

```
public bool isUserExist(string username,string password)
{
    bool status=false;
    try
    {
        string connstring = "data source=test_db;user id=system;password=password;";
        string statementcmd = "SELECT * FROM register_user Where [UserName]=@username";

        using(OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstring))
       {

        using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
       {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", username);//add parameters before assigning it to CommandText
        cmd.CommandText = statementcmd;

        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Open();
           OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            if (!reader.Read())
            { MessageBox.Show("User Name Not Found"); }

            if (!password.Equals(reader["password"].ToString())) 
            {
                 status=true;
                 MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Password");

            }


        }
      }

     }

   }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        status=false;
    }

return status;

}
```

Comment: @xXghostXx : i think UserName is reserved word in Oracle wrap it in square brackets `[]` see my edited answer...

Comment: i tried to alter the whole column name to "uname" and either the argument name to un, but same error keep happened